# jQuery and updatePanel combining - multiple input elements

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I've a designing problem with combining ASP.NET (forms, update panels) with jQuery.

Application contains multiple input  elements (textboxes, checkboxes, dropdowns etc.)  all of them need to autopostback (some long-time server-side calculations, on all). Basically i cannot change this workflow.

I would like to use jQuery UI modal Dialog, with UpdatePanel, contains multiple autopostbacking inputs. I tried, but without success - jQuery dialog does not show after postback, or looses focus.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the jquery events after each partial postback. See this 
[jquery needs to rebind events on partial page postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760833/jquery-needs-to-rebind-events-on-partial-page-postback)

Answer (score 0):

you can register client side script after post back.

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(MyBase.Page, Me.GetType, ("dialogJavascript" + this.ID), "alert(\"Registered\");", True)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put the controls inside another page and open the dialog as an IFrame - that should fix the postback problem.