# ASP.NET: Injecting Javascript on runtime (With AJAX enabled)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, postback, client-server

My Imagebutton exists within a `ListView` object and an `UpdatePanel`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAttach" runat="server" OnClientClick="update('Clip','false','inc')" ImageUrl="~/Images/Image.png" CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
     </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

At the `ListView ItemCommand` event i perform a check to see if a record exists in a database.
If it does not exist, i simply add it.
Now, if the record exists, i would like to show a JavascriptMessage displaying that the record already exists.

```
 Private Sub ListView1_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCommand
       If Not RecordExists() Then 
          InsertRecord()
       Else
          Show JavascriptMessage (Record Already Exists!)
       End If
 End Sub
```

So how could i do that? I tried several different versions of the `Show JavascriptMessage`, but none worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lav's code is almost there, but because your elements are in an UpdatePanel you need to make the following changes:

```
sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>")
sb.Append("alert('TestMessage')")
sb.Append("</script>")
```

Actually, you can get rid of lines 1 and 3 because we're going to tell it to automatically add the script tags, so we can simplify and just say:

```
Dim s as String
s = "alert('TestMessage')"
```

Now, instead of using `ClientScript`, we're going to use `ScriptManager`.

```
If Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(t, "PopupScript") Then
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(t, "PopupScript", sb.ToString())
End If
```

Instead, we're going to use ScriptManager, like so:

```
If Not ScriptManager.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Me, "PopupScript") Then
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "PopupScript", s, True)
End If
```

Note that we use the `RegisterStartupScript` method because we want the script to be run as soon as the partial postback is complete.

Comment: Hello, could you take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612167/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-control

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/JavaScript_with_ASP_NET_2_0_Pages_Part1.aspx).

Here is the code snippet that you can use to show javascript message on demand

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>")
sb.Append("Alert('TestMessage')")
sb.Append("/script>")
'register with ClientScript 
'The RegisterStartupScript method is also slightly different 
Dim t As Type = Me.[GetType]()
If Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(t, "PopupScript") Then
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(t, "PopupScript", sb.ToString())
End If
```

Comment: I have already tried that but, it does not work. I guess it has something to do with partial postbacks.

Comment: @Chocol8, this code should work. If you're doing a partial postback you might have to use ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock instead of ClientScript.

Comment: @Chocol8 Have a look here: --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545290/does-the-clientscriptmanager-work-when-called-in-a-partial-postback

Comment: @Chocol8 - Try RegisterStartupScript instead? Also, if the 'AddScriptTags' or whatever is set to true, then make sure you DON'T include script tags in your StringBuilder.